# Save cookie data,string language not in English

Tags: php, javascript

I find the if i save a cookie by JS Function like below:(w3c school example)

```
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()+"; path=/project/");
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

And I use setCookie("hello","你好",30) to save a cookie and use php code to echo it:

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['hello'];
?>
```

It will output "%u4F60%u597D". not "你好"。

So I exchange the encode way in setCookie　function like below:

```
function encode_setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
//use encodeURIComponent encode string and decodeURIComponent decode it.
var c_value=encodeURIComponent(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()+"; path=/project/");
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

And use php echo it again.
It will output "你好"　as i want read from cookie.

I try this save cookie by PHP code and read it by JS. it also work well.

Or encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent is enough for save and read cookie in PHP and JS.

It's about the string save in cookie is not in English problem thanks.

Had more better solution about it?

I find the solution about it.

[jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. Read this page for an introduction to unicode:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html